# How to integrate $1/(1 + x^2)$ on a desert island?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Classically, one would integrate $1/(1 + x^2)$ using trigonometric substitution rules, thus obtaining:
$$ \int \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \; \textrm{d}x = \arctan(x) + C $$

Sadly, you're stuck on a desert island, and must **determine an algebraic expression, or a series of algebraic expressions of the integral of $1/(1 + x^2)$** to survive. However, you never took the time to remember the more complicated trigonometric identities. All you know about the trigonometric functions is what you can see by drawing out a circle, and comparing the graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$:

$$ \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \tan(x)$$

$$ \sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1 $$

$$ \sin(2n\pi) = 0, \;\cos(2n\pi) = 1, \;\sin(n\pi/2) = 1, \;\cos(n\pi/2) = 0 $$

$$ \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}\sin(x) = \cos(x) $$

$$ \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}\cos(x) = -\sin(x) $$

Essentially, you must derive the integral of of $1/(1 + x^2)$ from first principles. What should you do?

(To answer the question, you can make assumptions about stuff you might know which is not excluded by the above. e.g. you could claim that you know about Taylor series approximations of functions, and thus go about finding a solution in that way. The fewer assumptions you can make, the better your answer.)

Comment: Is an approximate numerical integration allowed?  That way, you can just throw rocks.

Comment: @Paul Sorry: you need to provide a solution that involves a closed form algebraic expression, or a series of closed form algebraic expressions.

Comment: Why is the classical substitution $x = \tan(u)$ not good enough? It doesn't require any more knowledge than you have given here.

Comment: What is your definition of $\arctan$? More broadly, what ideas from trigonometry do you mean to permit?

Comment: @Winther Hmm, that's true, I think what I am trying to get at is that $\arctan(x)$ is not a "valid" solution, because its not something you know about, if that makes sense?

Comment: @TravisWillse You do not know about $\arcsin$, $\arctan$, or $\arccos$.

Comment: What is arctan really: its nothing but the inverse of $\tan(x)$ (with some domain restrictions etc.). The classical derivation gives you exactly that: the integral equals $u + C$ where $u$ is determined via $x = \tan(u)$. This is again nothing but the definition of an inverse function. If you only know $\tan(x)$ then you can still find the integral via a root finding method: "try" different values of $u$ to find one that satisfy $x = \tan(u)$.

Comment: @user89 Can you use the inverse function theorem?

Comment: If a power series solution is OK, you can just integrate termwise in the geometric series $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$

Comment: @user89 The antiderivative *is* $\arctan x + C$, so if you're not allowed to refer to $\arctan$ it's not really clear what the question is. Are you just looking for expressions for $\arctan$ that don't refer explicitly to (inverse) trigonometric functions?

Comment: @Winther I agree with you, but somehow that violates the spirit of the question. I am having trouble figuring out why, but somehow the solution being $u + C$, where $x = tan(u)$ does not "seem right", in the sense that you simply don't know enough about how the inverse of $\tan$ behaves? Sorry, I am some trouble figuring out why I do not want to allow that approach in the question (and perhaps the answer to the question is related to this trouble?).

Comment: If so, Hans' suggestion might be an option, but NB the resulting series only converges on $(-1, 1]$ and so doesn't define an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ on all of its domain.

Comment: @HansLundmark agreed. That seems to be the only solution I can come up with too that is "first principles" flavoured. However, you still have to somehow determine the series representation of $1/(1 + x^2)$.

Comment: If you really want, you can use first principles to determine the $n$th derivative of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ and hence the expansion.

Comment: The series expansion is from sum of a geometric series, nothing more than that.

Comment: Just make the basic identities table for derivatives of elementary functions and their inverses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,x)$, and  $(1, x + \Delta x)$ has area $\tfrac12 \Delta x$. Shrinking it by a factor $1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ from the origin yields a triangle with one vertex on the unit circle and area $\tfrac12 (1+x^2)^{-1} \Delta x$. Therefore the area of the unit disc cut out by the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,x)$ is $$\frac12 \int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}$$ and this equals half the angle at the origin since the unit disc has total area $\pi$.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what OP wants, but I think this answer---which effectively describes $\arctan$ geometrically, night come closest.

Comment: This is beautiful and just what I am looking for! Not sure I understand the last bit about "half the angle at the origin" bit near the end. Can you clarify?

Comment: @user89 I mean that the area of the pizza slice shape is also equal to half of its angle at the tip.

Answer (score 6):

By defining $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ you may notice that this function fulfills the differential equation $f'(x)=1+f^2(x)$. 
It follows that the computation of $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ is horribly simplified by the substitution $x=\tan(t)$, and that's it.

Answer (score 6):

We only assume the Pythagorean Theorem, namely $$\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1\tag{1},$$
as well as integration via substitution and differential calculus. Via $(1)$ we may prove that $$\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x\tag{2}$$
so it becomes evident that $$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=1.\tag{3}$$
Thus, using $t\mapsto\tan x$ and $(3)$,
$$\int\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}dx=\int dx=x.$$
Since $t=\tan x$, $x=\arctan t$, and we are done.

Answer (score 5):

On this desert island, is it conceivable that, even though you have admittedly forgotten all about trigonometric identities, you still vaguely remember that there are such things as complex numbers, and contour integrals?

Then (in a wild moment, half-crazed by your isolation), if faced with the unfamiliar integral $\int_0^t\frac{du}{1+u^2}$, where $t \geqslant 0$, you might think of writing it as:
$$
\int_0^t\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\left(\frac{1}{1+iu} + \frac{1}{1-iu}\right)du = \frac{1}{2i}\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z},
$$
where $\gamma$ is the contour given by $\gamma(u) = 1/(1 + iu)$ for $-t \leqslant u \leqslant t$, which traverses the straight line segment between $1-it$ and $1+it$.

Then you might remember something about complex logarithms, a little of your lost knowledge of trigonometry might come flooding back - and all of a sudden, you might *see* that the value of the integral is $\arctan(t)$.

(The camera zooms back, and we see a ragged and unshaven figure capering over the sand, shouting "Eureka!")

Comment: Imaginative. I like it (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do if your arsenal of functions is limited. First of all show that no rational function can have its derivative equal to $1/(1+x^2)$. It is slightly harder to show that no algebraic function can have its derivative equal to $1/(1+x^2)$.

Thus the anti-derivative must be a new kind of transcendental function and that's a great thing because we have found something new and exciting on the desert island. Define a new function $$f(x) =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\tag{1}$$ and one can immediately see that $f$ is odd, continuous, differentiable and strictly increasing on $\mathbb {R} $. Next we can note that $$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_{1/x}^{1}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$ via substitution $t=1/z$ for $x>1$. Letting $x\to\infty $ we can see that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$ is convergent and equals $\int_{0}^{1}(1+t^2)^{-1}\,dt$.

In other words the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt} {1+t^2}$$ exists so that $f$ is bounded with $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) =\pm 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$ Let $$\alpha=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\tag{2}$$ and then we can show that $\alpha$ is the least positive value for which $\cos \alpha=0$.

To do so we put $t=x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the integral defining $\alpha$ and get $$\alpha=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{3}$$ and using integration by parts one can show that the above integral equals $$2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\tag{4}$$ Using integral $(3)$ and $(4)$ it can be easily seen that circumference of a circle of unit radius is $4\alpha$ and area of a circle of unit radius is $2\alpha$.

And thus we can identify $\pi$ with $2\alpha $ depending upon your chosen definition of circular functions and one immediately gets $\sin\alpha=1,\cos\alpha=0$.

The next step is obviously to invert $f$ and study the inverse function on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2) $ and it will be seen that $f^{-1}(x)=\tan x$. It is also instructive exercise to prove the functional equation $$f(x) +f(y) =f\left(\frac{x+y} {1-xy}\right)\tag{5}$$ for $|x|<1,|y|<1$.

Using these ingredients you can now develop a full theory of circular functions of a real variable based on definition $(1)$.

Comment: (+1) I was hoping for some such approach as this, but I couldn't work it out, so I resorted to a lazier idea instead - based on an analogy with defining $\log x$ as $\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$, as well as a vague memory of reading some stuff about elliptic integrals, "inversion", duplication and addition formulas, and so on. (I got away with it because, to my surprise, it turned out to be more than an analogy, but this answer feels more like a proper "desert island" solution.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: The approach in my answer is taken from G H Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*.

Comment: That's funny: when I was mulling over the question, I thought of looking in Hardy's book to see if I could find inspiration in his treatment of the logarithm function, but I decided not to, because the book is near the bottom of a tall, tottering pile. (No disrespect to Hardy, as most of my books are in tall, tottering piles.) I must dig it out after lunch, and have a look. Thank you.

Comment: When digging Hardy out of the pile, I also dug up R. M. F. Moss & G. T. Roberts, *A Preliminary Course in Analysis* (Chapman & Hall, London 1968), which turns out to give broadly the same development on pp.144-153.